# Spring 4 and Hibernate 4/c3p0 with Entity Manager don't start

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, c3p0, hibernate-entitymanager

I create the configuration of Spring + JPA/Hibernate/c3p0 on this way:

Spring-Servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nassoft.erpweb"/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="com.nassoft.erpweb.login.interceptor.AuthenticatorInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.nassoft.erpweb.*" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/nsm_erp" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="1234" />

        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="3000" />
        <property name="loginTimeout" value="300" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

I'm not using persistence.xml because I read in some places its not necessary in Spring 4 with Hibernate.

When I start the server it still loading and don't start in 45s (nor 180s) in Tomcat7.

I create a factory of EntityManager to use in my project:

```
package com.nassoft.erpweb.factory;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;

public class ConnectionFactory {

        @PersistenceUnit
        private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

        public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){
            if (entityManagerFactory == null){
                entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ERPWeb");
            }

            return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        }
}
```

I think my configuration is not correct, but I don't found any places with a good text about it.

Can someone help-me?

Edited.

Problem solved!
First: I applied **Dependency Injection** in each controller to bring the DAOs with IoC.
Second: I use the annotation `@Repository` to create a repository in each DAO that will receive my databases methods.
Third: I created the EntityManage in this way for each DAO:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager manager;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete answer. I"m just pointing you to a direction.

Spring cannot find the ConnectionFactory class of yours, so it will not inject the entityManagerFactory. Its not required for you to again create a singleton for passing the entityManager, so no ConnectionFactory class is required. Spring will do it for you by injecting into the DAO or Controller etc., for example you have the following DAO that gets the data.

```
@Service
public class SomeDAO {

     @AutoWire -- i'm not sure what you call for the entityManager.
     private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

}
```

There is more info [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/just-spring-data/9781449339845/ch04.html). Instead of @autowiring he is using manual injection. I your case ,you can try with autowiring.

Also make sure that you have these classes in the `<spring:component-scan />` path of the application context file or else the spring wont be able to recognize and inject the entity manager.

Comment: Your post is not exctly what I expect but it helps a lot like a anwser! Thank you very much!

Comment: @felipeocr Probably submit your answer as well so others will find it useful :)

Comment: I'll post it when I finish my entire solution! Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Entire solution posted! If someone has problems with these config, can use this post to solve! :)